# Are the $2\times 2$ symmetric matrices a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Ok so I am looking at Rings. I saw somewhere that the $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ is a ring. But if we look at matrix multiplication I am not convinced:

If $ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
b & c\\
\end{array} \right) $

and $ B = 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
y & z\\
\end{array} \right) $

then $AB = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
ax+by & ay+bz \\
bx+cy & by+cz\\
\end{array} \right) $

which is not symmetric?

What am I missing? Does $a=c$ and $x=z$? If so, why? The matrices aboves are still symmetric without those being equal.

Thank you

Comment: Look: $(AB)^T=B^TA^T=BA$. So, I think this set is a ring only if the multiplication was commutative.

Comment: @flawr Look the Crostul's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you observed correctly the symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices are **not** a ring (with the usual operations) since the set is not closed under multiplications; it is at least an additive subgroup though.

Examples where already given, but let me add one.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & d
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & b \\
0 & d
\end{pmatrix}  $$
which is not symmetric (unless $b=0$).

It is however true that the matrices of the form 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
form a ring and possibly this was what was meant in your source.

Indeed, the matrices form clearly an additive subgroup, and writing $I$ for the identity matrix and $J$ for the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
each such matrix can be written (uniquely) as $xI+ yJ$ with real $x,y$. Since we have $I^2 = I$, $IJ=JI= J$ and $J^2 = I$, and the distributive law, it follows that the matrix is again of the claimed form.

Furthermore, we get from this consideration that this ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2 -1)$. Since $X^2 - 1$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ this is not a field, and we get that a further isomorphism to  $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X -1) \times \mathbb{R}[X]/(X +1) \cong \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

In this context it might also be interesting to recall that one way to construct the complex numbers is as matrices of the form 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}
$$
There the polynomial we get is $X^2 + 1$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to construct a counterexample. Take any 2x2 symmetric matrices and look at their product. Is it symmetric? Try.

I tried with

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
and $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
(just putting random numbers on the entries)

Comment: Yes, I have come up with examples that are not symmetric once multiplied. My question is: So the symmetric 2x2 matrices are not a ring? I saw it stated somewhere that it was so I am confused. Thanks

Comment: No: it is not a ring, since it is not closed under multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* a ring if both addition and multiplication are performed entrywise. If we use the usual matrix multiplication, however, the set does not form a ring, as you correctly observed.